# A determinantal formula

Tags: pr.probability, determinants

In my research, I encounter the following formula which I believe is correct (checked for $n\le3$). Is it classical ? If so, what is a reference ?

I am given a real symmetric matrix
$$S:=\int Y(t)Y(t)^Td\mu(t),$$
where $\mu$ is a probability and $Y(t):\Omega\rightarrow{\mathbb R}^n$.

Let $\sigma_k(S)$ be the elementary symmetric polynomial in the eigenvalues of $S$. For instance, $\sigma_1(S)$ is the trace and $\sigma_n(S)$ the determinant. The following formula gives $\sigma_k(S)$ in terms of the Gram matrix $G_k(s_1,\ldots,s_k)$ whose entries are the scalar products $Y(s_i)\cdot Y(s_j)$.

> $$\sigma_k(S)=\frac1{k!}\int^{\otimes k}\det G_k(s_1,\ldots,s_k)\,d\mu(s_1)\cdots d\mu(s_k).$$

Remark that $S$ is positive semi-definite. The integrand is non-negative, as well as $\sigma_k(S)$. The integrand vanishes identically iff $Y(t)$ takes values in a subspace of dimension $<k$, which is the condition under which $\sigma_k(S)$ vanishes. It follows that, if the formula above failed, it would be because of an inequality between strictly positive numbers.

**Edit**. I delete the question mark in the formula above, because Marcel's answer and my comment to it, yield a proof.

Comment: Is it correct that the last sentence in the OP implies 'you already know for sure that *if* the proposed equation is false, then the it fails *at most* in the form (positive real number)$\neq$(some other positive real number)'? I.e., it is for sure that it cannot fail in the form $0\neq$(positive real number)?

Comment: @PeterHeinig Yes, this is what I mean.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/66549/discussion-on-question-by-denis-serre-a-determinantal-formula).

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The case $k=n$ is a consequence of the identity

$$\int  \det(f_j(s_k))\det(g_j(s_k))\prod_{j=1}^N d\mu(s_j) = N!\ \det\left(\int d\mu(t) f_j(t)g_k(t)\right)$$

which I have seen under the names "Andreief identity" and also "Gram identity". The proof is elementary using the Leibniz formula for the determinant.

Comment: Oups! I should have found this one, since I use Andreif identity (and reprove it actually) in my last paper ...

Comment: @DenisSerre Proof for $k<n$ should be very similiar. Your formula is then a nice generalization of Andreief.

Comment: Now, I think I see a proof. It consists in expanding $\det(I_n+xS)$. Write $I_n+xS=e_1e_1^T+\cdots+e_ne_n^T+xS$, which is an $S'$, for a mesure $\mu'$ (which has to be divided by $n+x$ in order to qualify as a probability). Then apply the (proven) case $k=n$, and check carefully what is the coefficient of $x^k$.

Comment: The Andreief formula is just the discrete sum $\rightarrow$ continuous sum version of the Binet-Cauchy formula. The latter involves set of rows/columns instead of tuples which accounts for $N!$.